# How long does it take to die from drowning?

Tags: death, drowning

Here is the text I'm having trouble with (from *Foundations of Legal Research and Writing* 5th Edition by Bast and Hawkins):

> To their horror, they saw two bodies in the deep end of the pool. They all jumped into the pool and pulled out the bodies. The two women tried to revive Joseph and Phil while the two men called the police and fire departments. When they arrived, the police and firefighters joined the Andersons and the Cookes in trying to revive the two boys. The two boys were rushed to the hospital but died a few hours later.

A few hours later?  Is that plausible (realistic)?

Comment: Actual death and announced dead are not the same.  Hospital will try revival methods.

Comment: @Paparazzi - The text doesn't say "but were pronounced dead a few hours later."  (I could swallow that.)  It says "but died a few hours later."

Comment: @aparente001 Simply a common misuse of the words by journalists and authors. (And I don't understand the downvote.)

Comment: It does seem very odd to me that they don't say "pronounced dead a few hours later" but rather that they "died a few hours later." Maybe just bad writing? I disagree with Carey that it is "very realistic" that they were still alive hours after they got to the hospital. Pronounced dead is more likely.

Comment: Most likely they still had beating hearts, but pulmonary edema and electrolyte disturbances made it impossible to keep them alive.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know it depends on how much damage it has been done to the brain firstly and the  other organs. 
Usually the first cells to die in the brain are  those located in hypotalamus and they start dying within 3 minutes and as the lack of oxygen progresses other brain cells die to.

The last important organ that is heart starts dying at 15 minutes. So probably if you rescue the person now and start CPR it will live but with brain damage(the worst here being a vegetative state due to major brain damage).

Also another big factor in cell death is the metabolic rate of cells which slows down considerably in very cold water temp. In my uni Emergency book it is said that people could stay drowmed in cold water for up to 45 m and live.

I hope my answer helped you, but I'm pretty sure you can find a  ER professional healthcare staff around here which will provide way better answe than this.

Comment: I don’t have much to add to that. Maybe you can just quote your Emergency book and give a source, and point out that the victims were dead once (drowned), resuscitated and died (most likely) from the consequences of the cardiac arrest and weren’t able to be revived then. But a solid answer, +1 from me

Comment: @Narusan-sedated and Kermilli, can you spell out for me how long the whole process might take?  To my eye, that "died a few hours later" looks strange.  If a child or teen is taken lifeless from the water, and does not respond to the first responders' attempts to resuscitate, but then does respond to the ER staff's efforts, what's the most amount of time that might go by between pulling from the water, and successfully getting revived?  Can it really be several hours?

Comment: @aparente001 The way I understand the story is that locals on scene were able to resuscitate the patient, but the patient died later nonetheless due to other consequences.

Comment: @Narusan-sedated - I guess it's the glass half empty or half full.  I take "trying to revive the two boys" to mean they weren't having much luck.

Comment: Well, if you get someone out of the water lifeless, they are already (clinically) dead because their heart stopped beating for sure. So for them to die later on, they must have come back to life - in my understanding. CPR is not performed for hours until the patient is pronounced dead.

Comment: @Narusan-sedated - It can also mean *appearing dead*.  If you pull someone out of a pool, and the person is unable to move or react to you, and you don't have the training to check whether the person is dead, that's a situation where the word *lifeless* would fit.

Comment: @aparente001 I wish you had included in your question your statement above that `locals on scene were able to resuscitate the patient`. That's vital information that needs to be in the question, not in comments buried below.

Comment: @CareyGregory - I quoted the text exactly as it appeared in the book.  This idea that the locals were able to resuscitate the patient was invented by Narusan-sedated.  For the purposes of the homework exercise in the book I cited, it was *necessary* for the two children to die -- so we students could research the legal aspects of the death, negligence, liability, etc.  My question is whether the author's mention of the deaths occurring several hours after the children were pulled out of the water made sense.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's very realistic.

The boys were apparently clinically dead when found. [*Clinical death*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clinical_death) means there is no pulse or respirations. Clinical death is not necessarily permanent. CPR, defibrillators, and drugs can sometimes reverse the situation.

Clinical death is different from [*legal death*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_death), which is what happens when a doctor declares someone dead.

The most likely scenario is pulses were never restored, but they were young and previously healthy so a lot of time and effort was expended trying to resuscitate them. It was quite possibly a few hours.

This is a very common scenario. When you read that someone was taken to the hospital in cardiac arrest and died hours (not days) later, what that usually means is the hospital spent hours trying to save them but failed. They most likely never regained pulses. The time of death is reported when the doctor in charge gave up and declared them dead, not when their hearts stopped.

Comment: Thanks -- this is helpful.  // Instead of "If you're going to drown, do it in salt water," don't you mean, "If you're going to run into trouble in the water, do it in salt water"? // Note that the text doesn't say anything about pulse or respiration.  Also note that the four adults may be assumed to not have any special expertise with medicine or emergency response.  They can't be relied upon to correctly perceive pulse or respiration -- they haven't had the training, and also they're busy freaking out.

Comment: Carey, can you spell out for me how long the whole process might take? If a child or teen is taken apparently lifeless from the water, and does not respond to the first responders' attempts to resuscitate, but then does respond to the ER staff's efforts, what's the most amount of time that might go by between pulling from the water, and successfully getting revived?

Comment: @aparente001 You're asking additional questions that are impossible to answer. That's not what comments are for. Ask a new question.

Comment: I'm trying to clarify my original question.  For one thing, there was nothing in my question to indicate that the four adults managed to achieve a pulse.  Then, I'm not asking how long it takes to continue to attempt a heroic rescue, i.e. how long it takes to accept that the heroic rescue attempts aren't working.  All along I have asked, how long does it take to die?  I have a hard time believing that it takes at least 2 1/2 hours.

Comment: @aparente001 So you didn't understand my answer at all. I'm not sure what I can tell you then.

Comment: Let me try to be clearer.  In your "edit," you wrote, "apparently rescuers were able to restore pulses."  WE DON'T KNOW THAT.  That is an unfair assumption.

Comment: @aparente001 Okay, fine, I deleted the edit. End of discussion.

Comment: @CareyGregory *They most likely never regained pulses* - While I‘m uncertain what they actually do in the hospital apart from CPR when someone is under cardiac arrest - are they so good at imitating heart and lung that they see realistic chances of survival of the patient even after hours? As far as I am aware of the situation here, responders on site will try resuscitation usually before transportation into a hospital and if there aren’t any other apparent issues, they never get transported unless a pulse has been restored. Maybe I‘ll ask a new question.

Comment: @Narusan-sedated In the US the usual practice is for paramedics to provide three rounds of ACLS at the scene, and if a heartbeat isn't restored that's it. The patient is dead. But with pediatric patients and arrest due to drowning, a lot more effort is going to be made. I've never seen a pediatric patient left at the scene except in extreme trauma cases where clearly nothing can be done. Who knows what happened at the hospital. Maybe they got pulses restored but lost them again. Spending hours is unusual.

Comment: @CareyGregory - I'm reading a book by a trauma surgeon called "Trauma Red," and from some incidents he describes, I have the impression that when the ER personnel isn't pulled away to higher priority cases, for pediatric patients it is not unusual to keep trying, well beyond rational hope.  It seems to be an understandable response to their sadness and frustration.

Comment: @aparente001 Pedi patients will always get longer, more intense effort. Whether anyone wants to admit it or not, the younger you are, the more effort is going to be expended.